# Uploading very large android apps

Tags: android, file, console

I'm working on a tablet app which uses quite a lot of video, so the app size is quite large. 
At Google I/O 2011 they announced that the Android Market will be able to support apps up to 4GB as a 50 mb app and up to two 2GB data archives. I don't see any reference to this on the Developer Console and am unsure how to work with the data archives.

Here's a reference to the Google I/O presentation:
http://www.androidpolice.com/2011/05/11/io-2011-google-increases-app-size-limit-to-4gb-tweaks-the-return-policy/

If anyone could point me at the right docs or tell me how this works, I'd appreciate it.

Thanks,
Jens

UPDATE: This is finally available!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the change ever happened as they promised.

Comment: Can anyone else confirm this?